# String Handling - Error with substr_replace

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-replace

I have a specific condition where I need to replace every instance of a "ct" with "c-t" provided there is a consonant before 'c' and a vowel after 't'. I am unable to do so :

```
<?php

$string = "october solatrix regnum sanctus sanctus";

echo constantCT($string);

function constantCT($string)
{
    $arr1 = str_split($string);
    $length = count($arr1);
    $pc=0;

    for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++)
        {
            $check = $arr1[$j+1].$arr1[$j+2];
            if($check=='ct')
                {
                    $pc++;
                }
        }

    function strAppend4($string)
    {
        $arr1 = str_split($string);
        $length = count($arr1);

        for($z=0;$z<$length;$z++)
            {
                $check = $arr1[$z+1].$arr1[$z+2];
                if($check == 'ct')
                    {
                        //echo "ct found <br>";
                        //echo $arr1[$z]; echo "<br>";
                        //echo $arr1[$z+3]; echo "<br>";
                        $verifyC = isConstant($arr1[$z]);
                        $verifyV = isVowel($arr1[$z+3]);

                        if($verifyV && $verifyC)
                            {
                                echo $z+2; 
                                $updatedString = substr_replace($string, "-", $z+2,0);
                                //echo $updatedString;
                                return $updatedString;
                            }
                    }
                else
                    {
                        //echo "ct not found <br>";
                    }
            }
    }

    $st1 = $string;
    for($k=0;$k<$pc;$k++)
        {
            $st1 = strAppend4($st1);
        }

    return $st1;

}
```

So I should get the output as :

```
october solatrix regnum sanc-tus sanc-tus
```

The `ct` in `october` should not be tampered with as before 'c' there is a vowel and not a consonant.

Comment: A function defined within a function? Ouch...

Comment: `preg_replace()` seems like a better way to do this, using lookarounds to match the consonant and vowel.

Comment: Your title is misleading, please add the error you are getting, it's not related to `substr_replace` anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a regex using character classes.

```
echo preg_replace('/([^aeiou]c)(t[aeiou])/', '$1-$2', 'october solatrix regnum sanctus sanctus');
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/659567

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Nqiaav/1

or with a stricter character class:

```
echo preg_replace('/([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]c)(t[aeiouy])/', '$1-$2', 'october solatrix regnum sanctus sanctus');
```

https://regex101.com/r/Nqiaav/2 (can add/remove `y` if that isn't a vowel)

Also this assumes you only wanted lowercase, if you want to allow upper case as well use the `i` modifier, or add all capitals to the character classes.

Comment: I am trying to make a regex that puts a '-' between two vowels however it should ignore ae,oe,au could you please help me?

Comment: What about substitution?

Comment: Well that would find the dual vowels. To substitute you'll need to separate them, `(?!ae|oe|au)([aeiou])([aeiou])` then `$1-$2` Your regex is locked so can't provide an update there.

Comment: Success with that?

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry I fell asleep. Yes single syllable are success however error with complex strings. Could you check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006835/combine-multiple-regex-into-one

Comment: Well that's a different question which will require a longer regex but should be an adaption of what I've posted here. Have you tried Casimir's answer? If you have issues with that answer you should ask there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($j=0;$j<strlen($string);$j++)
        {
            if($string[$j] == 'c' && $string[$j+1] == 't')
                {
                    substr_replace($string, '-', $j+1, 0);
                    $j += 2;
                }
        }
echo $string;
```